# Is there a way to dynamically change a css class by a columns value?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if it's possible to use a column value from a SharePoint list to dynamically be the value of a link or a word's style class?

Like `<a class="<% value of column %>" href="thislink.com">Link name </a>`
or perhaps something with the same effect using jQuery?

Comment: Do you want to implement it in Listview or any form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break down your requirement it is:

#### get the value

This all depends where your value is

Do you have to scrape it off the page ?
or are you creating the page and know the value upfront (like with CSR/JSLink) ?

`var myClass='myFancyClass';`

#### get the element

No need for jQuery, vanilla JavaScript syntax is enough
It all comes down to applying (CSS) Selectors

Example:

`var targetElement = document.querySelector("a [href*='thislink']")`
gets the A element which contains 'thislink' in the href

- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [The 30 selectors you must memorize](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

#### apply the value

Once you have the element, you apply the class

`targetElement.classList.add( myClass );`

or fancier

`targetElement.classList.toggle( myClass );`

- These methods are IE10+ , for IE9 you have to manipulate the element.className **string** (be careful not to destroy other applied classes)
- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Hello Danny , pleaser pardon the late reply, My, you are remarkably concise. But let me ask how do I use a value from a data view like this to  become the class? <xsl:value-of select="order status" />. So effectively it would be class="<xsl:value-of select="order status" />..Is this possible?

Comment: There was no XSLT tag on your answer...You can stock up on [Tylenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tylenol_(brand)) and try and work JavaScript into the XSLT.. or just add JavaScript on the page which scrapes the value out of the HTML the XSLT creates... It is helpful to at least set a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) or id value with XSLT so you can get at the element with a simple selector (getElementById or querySelector)